# Ansible Jinja2 Template: how to compare string in case insensitive or force a readlink into lower/upper case?

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I have to use a jinja2 template for ansible and I am having issues with a particular string. I need to find a way to compare case insensitive and for some reason the |lower or |upper filter is not working on the following variable when I pull it from a readlink command:

```
temp=$(readlink -f "{{ symbolic_link }}")
{% set  directory = '$(temp)' %}
{% if directory|lower == random_string|lower %}
```

Essentially whatever the readlink is returning seems to be immutable and the |lower or |upper filter is having no effect on it. I also tried directory.lower() etc and none of the filters actually affect the string.

Any idea on how I can compare this directory variable to another one and have it be case insensitive? I am only having issues with the string when its produced from the readlink command.

Comment: I don't think you're comparing the strings you think you are. In this case "directory" should literally be '$(temp)' not any value expanded from the shell script?

It really helps to provide enough code to reproduce the problem to get good answers on stackoverflow.

Comment: Yes I agree, is there a way to attain that value as a normal string? It seems like the "directory" variable is just a pointer to whatever got returned from the shell command. I think that is why the filters are not doing anything to it

Comment: Yes, but not in pure Jinja. Look at the shell/cmd modules, and their "register" docs.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what you're doing here. Ansible itself isn't going to read that readlink at all. I don't think you're comparing the strings you think you are. The value of "directory" should literally be "$(temp)" here.

As for the comparison, yeah, that is the way to do it. If you want to verify for your own sanity, play around with this playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:
  - name: debug
    ansible.builtin.debug:
      msg: "Hello World!"
    vars:
      one: "Hello"
      two: "HeLlO"
    when: one | lower == two | lower
```